# How would I implement this dynamic controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am working on .NET Core 5 MVC. This is probably a xy problem.

I am trying to stream a `.m3u8` file to a browser video player (video.js). The video player reads the `.m3u8` and will try to request a `.ts` file for the video segments of it and will stream them in order according to the `.m3u8` file.

I have a controller called `Video`. In this controller, I have an action called 'GetStream' which returns the `.m3u8` file on the computer.

This is the request:

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44333/Video/GetStream Request 
Method: GET Status Code: 200  Remote Address: [::1]:44333 Referrer 
Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

The response:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 172
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Fri, 23 Jul 2021 18:21:58 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 23 Jul 2021 17:50:41 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

That is response is correct. The issue is that when the video player tries to get the `.ts` files from the information in the `.m3u8` `GetStream` file, it sends this request:

```
Request URL: https://localhost:44333/Video/2021-07-23_12-50-350.ts
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 
Remote Address: [::1]:44333
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

And of course, that returns a 404 error since there is no action that would return that file.

==============================================================

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult GetStream()
{
    return PhysicalFile(@"C:...\wwwroot\vods\2021-07-23_12-50-35.m3u8", "application/octet-stream", enableRangeProcessing: true);
}
```

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Did you try adding an action to return `.ts` files?

Comment: @abdusco What do you mean by that?

Comment: Similar to `GetStream` method, one that takes `.ts` filename as route parameter and streams the actual `.ts` file

Comment: `[HttpGet("{**tsFilename}")] public ActionResult GetTsFile(string tsFilename)`

Answer (score 1):

I had to do some route changes on the  actions to redirect it to the right spot.

```
    [HttpGet("[controller]/GetStream")]
    public FileResult GetStream()
    {
        return PhysicalFile(@"C:\..\wwwroot\vods\2021-07-23_13-52-52.m3u8", "application/octet-stream", enableRangeProcessing: true);
    }

    [HttpGet("[controller]/{tsFileName}")]
    public ActionResult GetTsFile(string tsFileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tsFileName))
            return new EmptyResult();

        return PhysicalFile(@"C:\..\wwwroot\vods\" + tsFileName, "application/octet-stream", enableRangeProcessing: true);
    }
```

Thanks to [@abdusco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5298150/abdusco) for pointing me in the right direction