# Streaming RTSP (AspNet 5 API, FFMPEG, Angular 10, videoJs)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, ffmpeg, rtsp, video.js

**Description**:

I have an API (ASP.Net 5) which connect to an IP Camera through RTSP. The camera send a h264 stream converted with ffmpeg as m3u8 stream which is returned to the angular client as follow:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> GetCameraH264Stream()
{
        string deviceIp = "rtsp://[CAMERA_IP]/";
        string recordingUri = "rtsp://[USER:PASSWORD]@[CAMERA_IP]/axis-media/media.amp";
        
        string output = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid() + ".m3u8");
        var mediaInfo = await FFmpeg.GetMediaInfo(recordingUri);

        var conversionResult = FFmpeg.Conversions.New()
            .AddStream(mediaInfo.Streams)
            .SetOutput(output)
            .Start();
        
        // Allow any Cors
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        
        // Open the file, and read the stream to return to the client
        FileStreamResult result = new FileStreamResult(System.IO.File.Open(output, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read), "application/octet-stream");
        result.EnableRangeProcessing = true;
        return result;
}
```

If I call this methods directly, the browser download a file, which I can read with VLC.

In my Angular app, I have this component:

**app-vjs-player**:

```js
@Component({
       selector: 'app-vjs-player',
       template: '<video #target class="video-js" controls muted playsinline preload="none"> 
                  </video>',
       encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    })
export class VjsPlayerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('target', {static: true}) target: ElementRef;
  
  @Input() options: {
      fluid: boolean,
      aspectRatio: string,
      autoplay: boolean,
      sources: {
          src: string,
          type: string,
      }[],
      vhs: {
        overrideNative: true
      },
  };
  player: videojs.Player;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // instantiate Video.js
    this.player = videojs(this.target.nativeElement, this.options, function onPlayerReady() {
      console.log('onPlayerReady', this);
    });
    
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // destroy player
    if (this.player) {
      this.player.dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

This component is used like this:

**TS**:

```js
playerOptions = {
    fluid: false,
    aspectRatio: "16:9",
      autoplay: false,
      sources: [{
          src: 'https://localhost:44311/api/GetCameraH264Stream',
          type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
      }],
}
```

**HTML**:

```html
<app-vjs-player #videoJs [options]="playerOptions"></app-vjs-player>
```

**Problem**

All this seems to work pretty well, until vjs throw this error when the api return the stream :

> ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported

When I open the network dev tools, the request status is "Canceled", but I don't know if  videojs cancel it because the filestreal can't be read, or if it is because of the way the API return the stream.

Any idea ?

**Source**

[Forwarding RTSP stream from IP Camera to Browser in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69899709/forwarding-rtsp-stream-from-ip-camera-to-browser-in-asp-net-core)

[VideoJs Angular integration](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-angular.html)

[Xabe.FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.xabe.net/docs.html)

***EDIT***

- I tried to limit the resolution and the bitrate but I can't configure the camera like that, there is other application using it. The camera do not have any streaming url allowing this configuration
- I have been able to get an image from my code after changing the content type of the api response. I changed:

```csharp
FileStreamResult result = new FileStreamResult(System.IO.File.Open(output, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read), "application/octet-stream");
```

to

```csharp
FileStreamResult result = new FileStreamResult(System.IO.File.Open(output, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read), "application/x-mpegURL");
```

With this the first packet is displayed, but the next requests are still canceled.

Comment: It may be a server or network failure, or an unsupported format.This article is similar to your situation, I hope it will help you:https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/4751

Comment: Hi, the github issue you linked is talking about android/tablet incompatibility, which is not really my problem. But there is this comment: "I also guess the reason is metadata error. Just as you said: a high bitrate, too many frames per second.".  I'll try to limit this and edit for the result

Comment: Are you having problems with the browser?

Comment: I'm under an enterprise network, so I can only use chrome and edge. I have the same problem on both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change on the response ContentType is working (see last edit on question).

It seems that the canceled request was triggered by the slow network. All the code above is working as is, except for the last modif ( application/octet-stream => application/x-mpegURL ). Here is the updated api method:

```csharp
public async Task<ActionResult> GetCameraH264Stream()
{
        string deviceIp = "rtsp://[CAMERA_IP]/";
        string recordingUri = "rtsp://[USER:PASSWORD]@[CAMERA_IP]/axis-media/media.amp";
        
        string output = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid() + ".m3u8");
        var mediaInfo = await FFmpeg.GetMediaInfo(recordingUri);

        var conversionResult = FFmpeg.Conversions.New()
            .AddStream(mediaInfo.Streams)
            .SetOutput(output)
            .Start();
        
        // Allow any Cors
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        
        // Open the file, and read the stream to return to the client
        FileStreamResult result = new FileStreamResult(System.IO.File.Open(output, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read), "application/x-mpegURL");
        result.EnableRangeProcessing = true;
        return result;
}
```

***EDIT***

It seems that the code above will create a ffmpeg.exe process each time a request is made. This process will never end, as this is a stream from a camera that is never ended. I don't know how to kill the ffmpeg process yet, but I have modified the stream conversion retrieval so it use an existing ffmpeg process for the stream if it already exist:

```csharp
public async Task<ActionResult> GetCameraH264Stream()
{
        string deviceIp = "rtsp://[CAMERA_IP]/";
        string recordingUri = "rtsp://[USER:PASSWORD]@[CAMERA_IP]/axis-media/media.amp";

        
        if (!this.cache.GetCache("camstream").TryGetValue(streamingUri, out object output)) 
        {
                output = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid() + ".m3u8");
                var mediaInfo = await FFmpeg.GetMediaInfo(streamingUri);
                var conversionResult = FFmpeg.Conversions.New()
                .AddStream(mediaInfo.Streams)
                .SetOutput((string) output)
                .Start();
                this.cache.GetCache("camstream").Set(streamingUri, output);

                // Delay until the file is created
                while (!System.IO.File.Exists((string)output))
                {
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                }
        }

        // Allow any Cors
        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        // Open the file, and read the stream to return to the client
        FileStreamResult result = new FileStreamResult(System.IO.File.Open(output, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read), "application/x-mpegURL");
        result.EnableRangeProcessing = true;
        return result;
}
```

And for the .ts file :

```csharp
private async Task<ActionResult> GetCameraH264StreamTSFile(string tsFileName)
{
            string output = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), tsFileName);
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return File(System.IO.File.OpenRead(output), "application/octet-stream", enableRangeProcessing: true);
}
```